# How are the winners of ties determined in Capture the Flag?

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battlefield 3's Capture the Flag game mode, ties happen quite a lot, with neither team reaching the requisite 3 captures and ending up with the same amount as the other team (Sometimes 0-0). But there doesn't seem to be consistency on who is the "winner" in these cases.

It does not appear to be whoever is closer to gaining another flag, as I lost a match when our flag carrier was only feet from scoring the final flag when time ran out.

It does not appear to be who was ahead for longer, as I've played matches where my team was up 2-0 for most of the game, then the other team tied it up near the end of the match.

Is there any official word on how this winner is determined? Barring that, is there any good explanation for one reason or another?

Comment: Flagged as too flaggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my own experience (and I play it a lot), when the flag captures are tied, the team with the **higher score** wins (total points of all players of the team).

More specific from the [Battlefield 3 Wikia](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_the_Flag)

> In the event of a tie by equal number of flags captured by both teams, there is a winner, this is determined by the team with the highest cumulative score. In the rare occasion that both teams have an equal cumulative score, the victor will be the US team by default.

Additional sources:

- https://twitter.com/gustavhalling/status/311736490830991360